# "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro'"; android studio ; flutter

Tags: android, flutter

the error I am facing:

[image]

what I tried to do:

[image]

I tried adding this packagingOptions and the exclude but it is not working  what can I do to solve this error

The problem is with the firebase packages when I added them the error appeared so I will show you what I did for adding firebase to the project maybe that will help in solving the problem

### project/build.gradle

```
[project/build.gradle][1]
```

### the packages

```
[the packages][2]
```

### app/build.gradle

```
[the gradle app file][3]
[the gradle app file][4]
[the gradle app file][5]
```

thank you for your cooperation

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5DTs.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx95B.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSbKj.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ9Dy.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Offkw.png
```